# How to add lines to a TabbedPane in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, jtabbedpane

This is my code thus far:

```
Public TabbedPaneGraphic{
    super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("");

    for(int i=0; i< 4; i++)
    { 
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Name " + i , icon, panel,
        "Panel " + (i+1));
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);
    }

    add(tabbedPane);
    tabbedPane.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));        
    tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
}
```

I wish to add a grid made of lines to each individual tabbed panel, conditional on what "i" is (e.g. drawLine(0,i,0,100*i)). However, I do not see any way to add such a grid in the "for" loop-- is this even possible? If not, how would I do it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a JTable to be displayed in the JTabbedPane? Or do you really just want to draw lines across the component in your JTabbedPane?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and you might want to consider adding some information about what it is you are trying to achieve and why as it will produce a better quality of answer